# CSS: LINK:HOVER background image seems to work but once hovered does not appear

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover, background-image

Example:

```
.twitter:LINK{
     width: 15px;
     height:15px;
     display:block;
     background-image: url('../_img/social_butt/twitter.jpg');
}

.twitter:HOVER{
     width: 15px;
     height:15px;
     display:block;
     background-image: url('../_img/social_butt/twitter_hover.jpg');
}
```

As you can see the code are identical and the path also. These two pictures are exactly in the same folder and I double checked the name. This is displayed as a background image inside a an `<a>` element.

The problem is that once you hover the link the status LINK dissapears (picture twitter.jpg) and instead of appearing right after the HOVER (picture twitter_hover.jpg) what you see s nothing. Therefore when you take out the mouse LINK appears again. The intention is to have a different hover image loaded once hovered.

Why is it not working?

NEW EDIT/////////////////////////////

It seems with comments of the rest that the code is correct. I also thought it was correct. I've crossed different images and I see I have only problems with the image I want to hover. I've tried different formats etc... and still the same. I even opened the LINK image and changed the color with photoshop and saved again as a jpg. Also not working...

I attach the two pictures to see if you know what could be the solution...[image][image]

Comment: just changed from display:block to display: inline-block. Just if its important for somebody...

Comment: this works for me.  http://jsfiddle.net/tomprogramming/FGt9Z/

Comment: Thanks Kirean... the code is correct. Just discovering something strange regarding the images. They are exactly the same format, only with different background color. I will update the pictures to see if the pcitures are the problem, lets see if its maybe the image itself.

Comment: Might also be worth noting that a 15x15 twitter icon would likely be more efficient as a sprite.

Comment: If it's an image thing, maybe one of them is in CMYK for some reason?

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero I just wanted to point out that your code should work as is.  There must be something funky with your image/files.

Comment: THe images are both RGB. I don;t find the problem so difficult to solve. What is a sprite? Why is it better for this?

Comment: In my last sentence I mean If I dont find the problem I wont be able to solve it. It felt a bit aggresive after the typos...

Answer (score 0):

i guess it has to be lowercase, and you need to respect the correct order:

LoVe HAte

link, visited, hover, active

```
a.twitter:link, a.twitter:visited {
     width: 15px;
     height:15px;
     display:block;
     background-image: url('../_img/social_butt/twitter.jpg');
}
a.twitter:hover, a.twitter:active{
     width: 15px;
     height:15px;
     display:block;
     background-image: url('../_img/social_butt/twitter_hover.jpg');
}
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be lowercase, and the order is already correct.

Comment: thanks... thats what I thought. Order correct and lowercase does not do affect